# Is it possible to add new UIBezierPath object to an array each time a taps and drags on the screen so that it can be undone?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am trying to add a **UIBezierPath** to an array of tuples each time the user drags their fingers on the screen to make a drawing.

I initialize my variables

```
var arrayListFingerBezierPath: [(UIBezierPath, CGColor)] = []
var arrayListFingerPathUndoStore: [(UIBezierPath, CGColor)] = []
```

and in **touchesBegan** I have the lines

```
fingerPath?.move(to: currentTouchPoint)
arrayListFingerBezierPath.append((fingerPath!, strokeColor))
setNeedsDisplay()
```

In my **touchesMoved** I have the lines

```
fingerPath?.addLine(to: currentTouchPoint)
arrayListFingerBezierPath.append((fingerPath!, strokeColor))
setNeedsDisplay()
```

In **touchesEnded** I have the lines

```
fingerPath?.addLine(to: currentTouchPoint)
arrayListFingerBezierPath.append((fingerPath!, strokeColor))
setNeedsDisplay()
```

I am adding the `fingerPath` to an array so I can undo and redo paths.
My Undo function works like this

```
func undo()
{
    if(!arrayListFingerBezierPath.isEmpty)
    {
        arrayListFingerPathUndoStore.append(arrayListFingerBezierPath.removeLast())
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add new UIBezierPath object to an array each time the user touches and drags on the screen in such a way that the click of an undo button will remove the whole of the last stroke the user made?

I can post all the class code if you need it all.

Comment: You may want to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124385/uibezierpath-undo-drawing-redraw-uiimageviews-image

Comment: @Bappaditya I've had a look but that question and answer use Objective-C and doesn't really solve my problem